# Interaction of magnetic fields with the magnetic field produced by current?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

In this picture, the magnetic field from the permanent magnets exerts a force on this wire, and the direction and magnitude is described by $F = iL X B$

But doesn't the wire also generate a circular magnetic field in the clockwise direction? How does that interact with the magnetic field produced by the permanent magnet and does it also produce a force on them?

Also, is the force exerted by the permanent magnets due to the interaction between the magnetic field of the wire and the permanent magnets?

Comment: This question might seem stupid but any help is really appreciated since I'm having a hard time understanding magnetic fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the force **F** that you wrote is **not** due to the interaction between the two magnetic fields. I hope it is clear to you that any current put in the magnetic field will give rise to this force.

Yes, the wire does produce a magnetic field, which is circularly around it with the wire being the axis passing perpendicular to the plane of the circle and if the current is high enough,one would feel force due to this field on the magnetic poles. If you are reading from a book, ***it has probably neglected*** the field of wire in this instance.